# How can I update Android-SDK 23 to 26 in Ionic Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

The message I get:

```
cordova-android@6.3.0 cordova -v 8.0.0

Plugin doesn't support this project's android-sdk version. android-sdk: 23.0.0, failed version requirement: >=26
```

Answer (score -1):

use command

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

Comment: after doing this i got error

(node:5432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Comment: can i get your ionic info

Comment: cli packages: (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v6.11.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : D:\Android

Misc:

    backend : pro